# Group by week in the first column of an array ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the next bidimensional array, where the first componente belongs to ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone and the second component is a string

```
[[Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:41:56 -03 -03:00, "open"],
 [Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:41:56 -03 -03:00, "closed"],
 [Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:41:56 -03 -03:00, "closed"],
 [Mon, 10 Jul 2017 00:00:00 -03 -03:00, "open"],
 [Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:45:31 -03 -03:00, "closed"],
 [Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:44:41 -03 -03:00, "open"],
 [Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:44:39 -03 -03:00, "closed"],
 [Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:44:13 -03 -03:00, "open"],
 [Mon, 10 Jul 2017 00:00:00 -03 -03:00, "closed"],
 [Fri, 14 Jul 2017 00:00:00 -03 -03:00, "open"],
 [Mon, 17 Jul 2017 00:00:00 -03 -03:00, "open"]]
```

I need to convert that array in efficient way into

```
{["09-Jul", "open"]=>2, ["16-Jul", "open"]=>1, ["09-Jul", "closed"]=>0, ["16-Jul", "closed"]=>1}
```

That is, I need to convert the first component into the format %b-%d. Also, I need group by week and "status". Finally I need to count these grouped values and present the data with hash format as the second example

Comment: and what's the inefficient way you have come up with?

Answer (score 2):

```
input.group_by { |d, v| [d.strftime('%b-%d'), v] }
     .map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }.to_h
```

Also, for Ruby 2.4+ it could be simplified (credits go to @MarkThomas) to:

```
input.group_by { |d, v| [d.strftime('%b-%d'), v] }
     .transform_values(&:count)
```

Comment: The `map` and `to_h` could be replaced with `.transform_values(&:count)` in Rails 4.2+

Comment: @MarkThomas I am a graduated Rails-hater.

Comment: ...or [Ruby 2.4+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create the desired hash with the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument equal to the *default value* of the hash, which here we want to be zero. What that means is that if a hash `h`, defined `h = Hash.new(0)`, does not have a key `k`, then `h[k]` returns the default value (here `0`), without modifying the hash `h`.

```
input.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(d,v),h| h[[d.strftime('%b-%d'), v]] += 1
```